# couldn't find file 'store/spree_drop_ship'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce, spree

Please after installing the "dropship extension" I'm getting this error each time I try to load spree on the browser.

Sprockets::FileNotFound in Spree/home#index

Showing /home/dbldbl/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bundler/gems/spree-eabfb1f75ae2/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_head.html.erb where line #8 raised:

couldn't find file 'store/spree_drop_ship'
  (in /home/dbldbl/MyStoreWeb/MyStore-production_master/app/assets/stylesheets/store/all.css:10)

Extracted source (around line #8):

5: <%== meta_data_tags %>

6: <%= canonical_tag %>

7: <%= favicon_link_tag image_path('favicon.ico') %>

8: <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'store/all', :media => 'screen' %>

9: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

10: <%= javascript_include_tag 'store/all' %>

11:

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/dbldbl/MyStoreWeb/MyStore-production_master

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this before somewhere on here and had the same error mesage. i had to change the gem sprocket-rails 2.2.2 to 2.1.3 in the gem lock

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the lines referencing the drop_ship css and js files and it started working.